# Java int multiply by float loss of precision

Tags: java

```
int totalSum = ids.length() * price;

length is int
price is float
```

I get this error:

```
error: possible loss of precision
```

how to multiply int by float correctly without losing precision?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are getting result in int, which will ignore the values after decimal

try this

```
double totalSum = ids.length() * price;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal.intvalue`:

```
int i = new BigDecimal(ids.length).multiply(new BigDecimal(price)).intValue();
```

... or you can just cast the whole operation as `int`:

```
int totalSum = (int)(ids.length() * price);
```

**Edit**

As implied in comments, I'm making this explicit: casting as `int` or getting the `int` value will incur in a loss of precision.

Use Deepak's answer if you were just not sure about which type to pick (and accept his answer).

Comment: ohh, but the end value will lose precision isn't?

Comment: @user3518675 yes it will.

Comment: I may be wrong cause I don't know JAVA, but mathematically speaking I don't find it very wise to store the result of a float multiplicatio in an Interger variable... even if that's what the OP writes in his code.

Comment: @Bartdude I actually agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float totalSum = (float) ids.length() * price;
```